# How do I get Debug/Trace.Writeline output from a WCF Service

Tags: wcf, trace

I have a WCF Service hosted in IIS. I am getting the WCF Tracing , but I can't find where my trace.writeline entries are going. My trace listener only logs the WCF Tracing.
Is there a specific Source I need to add to get this included.

Answer (score 6):

- Start the Event Viewer
- Open the Applications and Services logs folder
- -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Application Server-Applications
- Right click the Application Server-Applications folder and choose View -> Show Analytic and Debug Logs
- Expand the Application Server-Applications folder and right click the Debug log. Choose Enable Log.

If you know you run a WCF/WF service compiled in debug mode, the Debug.WriteLine() should be logged to the log.

Remember to disable the log when you're done with it.

--larsw